# v8 remote debugging c++

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I use remote debugging by socket connection with old v8 version. Remote debugging doesn't work with the newest v8 version. Because some methods are deprecated or removed from v8. v8-debug.h file is useless for debugging.

> // Schedule a debugger break to happen when JavaScript code is run
>     // in the given isolate.
>     V8_DEPRECATED("No longer supported",
>                   static void DebugBreak(Isolate* isolate));
>
> // Remove scheduled debugger break in given isolate if it has not
>   // happened yet.   V8_DEPRECATED("No longer supported",
>                   static void CancelDebugBreak(Isolate* isolate));
>
> // Check if a debugger break is scheduled in the given isolate.
>   V8_DEPRECATED("No longer supported",
>                   static bool CheckDebugBreak(Isolate* isolate));
>
> // This is now a no-op.   V8_DEPRECATED("No longer supported",
>                   static void SetMessageHandler(Isolate* isolate,
>                                                 MessageHandler handler));
>
> // This is now a no-op.   V8_DEPRECATED("No longer supported",
>                   static void SendCommand(Isolate* isolate,
>                                           const uint16_t* command, int length,
>                                           ClientData* client_data = NULL));

I can't find a guide to fix this issue. Is there any minimal c++ debugging example with v8-inspector?

Comment: Have you seen the official documentation at https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Debugging-over-the-V8-Inspector-API? Does it help?

Comment: @jmrk I have seen it. But it is complicated for me. We use Debug::SendCommand to send command to v8 with previous v8 versions. But now, do I create a InspectorClient?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check this sort article I wrote on the subject: https://medium.com/@hyperandroid/v8-inspector-from-an-embedder-standpoint-7f9c0472e2b7

Older debugger agent has been deprecated and removed from main codebase some time ago in favor of the inspector API, so you basically need to rewrite everything from scratch.

The tricky parts of the integration are:

- websockets as trasnsport between chrome dev tools and your running codebase (in my case, an Android app with embedded v8).
- appropriately handling them custom `runMessageLoopInPause` and `quitMessageLoopInPause` methods supplied in the InspectorClient.